# Divisibility Problem (Number theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

Well i just wanted you guys to check my solution to the following problem:

Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers of the form $ax+by$. Suppose $S$ is non empty and let $d=ax_o+by_o$ be the least element in $S$. Show that every element in $S$ is divisible by $d$.

My solution is as follows:

Let n be an element of $S$ such that $n$ = $ax+by$. Then there exists integers $q$ and $r$ with $0 \le r \lt d 
$,  such that $n=qd+r$. Substituting gives, $ax+by=q(ax_0+by_0)+r$ $\Rightarrow$  $r=a(x-qx_0)+b(y-qy_0)$.

But since as $ax_0+by_0\leq q(ax+by)$ $\Rightarrow$ $a(x-qx_0)+b(y-qy_0) \leq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $r \le 0$.

Hence, $0 \leq r \leq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $r = 0$. Hence, the result.

Thank you for reading upto here. If u have any suggestions you can freely leave it below.

$Correction:$ Thanks to [fleablood](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/280126/fleablood), [Wrench](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/702692/wrench) and others for the help!

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $r \ne 0.$

Note that, since $r>0$ and $r = a(x-qx_o)+b(y-qy_0)$ $r \in S$ . Note that  $r < d$  this contradicts the minimality of d.

Comment: The reasoning is not entirely correct. From your calculations, $r$ is a non-negative number of the form $ax+by$ and is less than $d$, thus contradicting the minimality of $d$. Therefore, $r = 0$.

Comment: "But since as ax0+by0≤q(ax+by) ⇒ a(x−qx0)+b(y−qy0)≤0 ⇒ r≤0." this is hard to follow and doesn't seem rightYou know $ax+by \le ax_0 + by_0$ but not that $ax+by < q(ax_0 + by_0)$.  $q$ could be zero or negative.......  I't be far simpler to simply note that as $r =a(x-qx_0) + b(y-qy_0)$ then if $r > 0$ then $r < S$.  But as $r < d$ and $d$ is the least element of $S$ then $r \le 0$.   And $0 \le r$ then $r = 0$.

Comment: "Let S be the set of all positive integers of the form ax+by" BTW it's not entirely clear what of the form $ax + by$ means.  Which of those variables are fixed and which are not? And as the result must be a positive integer it should be pointed out that $a,x,b,y$ *dont* have to be positive but they do have to be integers. (If they *are* positive the result is not true).  It should be written as something like: Let $a,b$ two fixed integers, let $S$ be the set of all positive integers of the form $ax+by$ for some integers (not necessarily positive) $x,y$.

Comment: By the way.  This result called Bezout's Lemma and it is *very* important.

Comment: @fleablood thank you and i just copied the question present in my book and i didnt get what you mean by r < S

Comment: Argh.... I had a typo!   " I't be far simpler to simply note that as $r=a(x−qx_0)+b(y−qy_0)$ then if $r>0$ then $r<S$. "  That should be: " I't be far simpler to simply note that as $r=a(x−qx_0)+b(y−qy_0)$ then if $ r>0$ then $r\in S$"

Comment: @fleablood yes i asked it and suddenly you replied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of all integers of the form $ax+by$ and let $d$ be the least positive element of $S$. We will show that $d=$[gcd(a,b)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20greatest%20common,8%20and%2012%20is%204.) (for some $x$ and $y$).

Since $d$ is an element of $S$ and $\gcd(a,b)$ divides all elements of $S$, we have $\gcd(a,b)\mid d$.

By the division algorithm, there exists integers $q$ and $r$ with $0\leq r<d$ such that $a=qd+r$. Then $r=a-qd=a-q(ax+by)=(1-qx)a-(qy)b$, so $r\in S$. But $r<d$, so $r=0$ and thus $d\mid a$. Similarly $d\mid b$, so $d\mid\gcd(a,b)$.

Since $d\mid\gcd(a,b)$ and $\gcd(a,b)\mid d$ then $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Hence as $x$ and $y$ vary, $ax+by$ attains only (and all) multiples of $\gcd(a,b)$, so every element of $S$ is divisible by $d$.

Comment: i havent reached the section of gcd in my book. But thanks!

Comment: I've added a link!

Comment: Okay thanks! ill check it out